# GWT-Platform revealing presenters together

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform, gwt-mvp

Hey so I am just learning the gwtp framework and I have come across a bit of a dilemma. I have a LayoutPresenter at the top level that has a main content slot and menu content slot and I am trying to find a way to bind my presenters for each slot together if possible so when the main content is revealed it will automatically show the correct side menu. Currently I have a static boolean in the Menu's Presenter that get updated onReveal and onHide. I can then check if the menu is visible when the main content is revealed and if not I reveal it.

```
    public class MenuPresenter extends Presenter<MenuPresenter.MyView, MenuPresenter.MyProxy> {

private static boolean hidden = true;
    ...
    @Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this, LayoutPresenter.SIDE, this);
}

@Override
protected void onReveal(){
    super.onReveal();
    hidden = false;
}

@Override
protected void onHide(){
    super.onHide();
    hidden = true;
}

public static boolean isHidden(){
    return hidden;
}
    }
```

Then in The main content Presenter:

```
    public class ContentPresenter extends
    Presenter<ContentPresenter.MyView, ContentPresenter.MyProxy> {

...

private final DispatchAsync dispather;
private final PlaceManager placeManager;

@Inject
public PhoneCallPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view, final MyProxy proxy, final DispatchAsync dispatcher, final PlaceManager placeManager) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy);
    this.dispather = dispatcher;
    this.placeManager = placeManager;
}

@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this, LayoutPresenter.CONTENT, this);
}

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    if (MenuPresenter.isHidden()){
        placeManager.revealPlace(new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.menu));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood the question, you want to have different side-menus for different main contents.
In this case there are two solutions:

1. Treat the menu as a normal Presenter (you will probably have multiple of them for each main content type). You just need to annotate the corresponding `MenuPresenter` with the same history token as your main content Presenter. So for the above example you would have a `PhoneCallMenuPresenter` that is annotated with the same history token as your `PhoneCallPresenter`. When you navigate to `/phonecall` (or whatever your history token is), both `PhoneCallPresenter` and `PhoneCallMenuPresenter` will be revealed automatically . (you don't have to do anything).
2. In case you want to have only one `MenuPresenter` and put the logic what to display in the `Presenter` itself, I would recommend to use a `PresenterWidget` instead of a normal `Presenter`. The `MenuPresenterWidget` will be injected into the `LayoutPresenter` and will be added to the `LayoutPresenter.SIDE` slot. You can define a setter for the `MenuPresenterWidget` to specify which main content is currently displayed (the setter will be called from the `LayoutPresenter` or you can override the `onReset()` method and check the current place request and decide what to display in the menu.

For solution 1 you have to have one `MenuPresenter` for each main content `Presenter` and potentially many code lines will be redundant (you could create a base `MenuPresenter` and derive from it). So in case you have a lot of business logic in the side-menu which is quite different from main content to main content, I would go with solution 1. In case you only display different links the overhead of creating a `MenuPresenter` per main content `Presenter` might be to high and I would go with solution 2 and create only one `MenuPresenterWidget` for all main content types and always show it.